# Execute search/replace in PhpStorm as action

Tags: phpstorm

I'm looking for a solution to:

1. store favorite "Find Occurrences of ..." and
2. execute them without any more questions by the UI in one stroke

I know the option `ALT + 3` -> `STRG + E` to open the last Find Usages, but that are only "Find" and not "Replace in Path" actions

Maybe I need to develop a plugin - that could look like this:

```
DO REPLACEMENTS:
----------------------------------
[X] foo -> bar
[ ] bar -> foo
[X] ): boolean -> ): bool
----------------------------------
[add] [execute] [execute & review]
----------------------------------
```

but any other ideas are welcome!

Important is to use PhpStorm`s file scopes! Because I would like to use my own custom scope.

Comment: There are no such functionality. You can try recording a macro though... (but it's unlikely to do what you want -- you cannot check what steps to run and when to stop). Otherwise -- code your own plugin -- the best and most flexible way from any POV.

Comment: Macros dont work (macros *never* works! if i try something with macros :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Structural Search Inspection". It's base on the ["Structural Search and Replace"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) engine which is pretty powerful. Once configured you can run the inspection using the "Run Inspection by Name..." action with a custom scope. It has a quick fix which can be used to replace occurrences.

Comment: That seems to be the Answer, but i dont get it work with what ive tried: class $class$ {
    public function $method$(): $returnType$ {
}

Comment: ...and can i get quick access to my saved searches by a toolwindow or keyboard shortcut or macro?

Comment: You can assign a shortcut on the "Search Structurally..." action, it doesn't have it by default. But I'd still recommend configuring "Structural Search Inspection" which runs a search automatically. Back to a search query you've mentioned. What are you trying to achieve? What would you like to find?

Comment: my goal is to define some preferences of search/replacement code templates to fix all my code style problems before the code sniffer tells me these errors ;-) ... as simple as possible. with a short-cut ..... I don't know how suitable code-templates are for this idea.

Comment: Nice Tip with "Structural Search Inspection" - Thanks - but i have trouble to learn how to use these templates...

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506157/intellij-structural-search-in-php-to-find-specific-return-types