# IntelliJ Structural Search in PhpStorm to find methods with specific return types

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, php-7, structural-search

How can I find the method **foo** with return type `boolean` in my example using **PhpStorm's Structural Search**?

```
<?php

class test {

    public function hello() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function foo(): boolean {
        return true;
    }

}

$t = new test();
$t->foo();
```

I've tried the following **search template**:

```
class $a$ {
 public function $show$(): boolean {
  $content$
 }
}
```

Where can I learn more about these code/search templates?

Comment: What you provide is PHP Code but you talking about intellij (without the s) and this is for Java. If you like to have something for PHP use PhpStorm. There you will have auto completion for PHP https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/. I don't thing you can do PHP stuff in intellij-idea

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that. I've adjusted my question.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently been in contact with JetBrains support about the structural search implementation in PhpStorm. The problem is that it is only partically implemented. Things like return types, inheritance, and more things that make structural search useful are currently not available (the options are there, but grayed out and they do not work).

This makes the number of use cases for structural search extremely limited, you are usually better off using different kinds of searches.

There is an open ticket about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174921

---

For your use case (finding functions with a boolean return type), I would recommend doing a regular expression search:

- Go to *Edit* -> *Find* -> *Find in Path*.
- Make sure *Regex* is checked and *Match cas*e is unchecked.
- Enter the following regex: `function[^}]+:\s*bool`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this:

```
class $class_name$ {public function $function_name$(): bool}
```

OR

Just use **bool** instead of **boolean** in the search template that you have.
[image]